# Right version for mockito and powermockito to run with testng and java8

Tags: maven, java-8, testng, mockito, powermockito

I want to know the compatible versions of mockito and powermockito to run with testng and java8. Tests are running fine with java 6, but when the application is upgraded to java 8, all the test cases involving powermock, fail. I also want to know if any additional dependecy is also required in the application to make tests run in java 8. Currently my maven dependencies for test are as follows :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-support</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any working example will do.

Comment: please add one minimal sample that fails in the way you experience it.

Comment: @RemigiusStalder I'm getting "test initialization error".

Comment: with an empty test or is there some additional code needed to get this error? in any case, for someone trying to help you, it might be helpful to get some code, i.e. a test class with one test method that fails.

Comment: @RemigiusStalder used the latest versions now getting "stackframe error" . Can you please post a working maven dependencies for test in java 8 with testng, mockito and powermockito.

Comment: can you please add a minimal test case which produces the said "stackframe error"

Answer (score 1):

How about using the latest version of each? testng 6.8 is from Sep 2012 (current is 6.9.9), mockito 1.9.5 is from Oct 2012 (current stable is 1.10.19), powermock 1.5 from Dec 2012 (current is 1.6.4) - which are all fairly outdated and before the advent of Java 8 (March 2014).

Also, try to use a property for repeated version numbers (e.g. the version of powermock), which makes it easier to change it.

Caveat: I have not tested this combination (due to lack of a test case - although requested), so I cannot guarantee that the combination of the latest stable versions as mentioned above will work. See also the respective web sites about comments on how to get everything to run properly.